# Search only headers and/or only in outline of Google Docs

Tags: search, headers, google-docs

I have a Google Doc with a large outline to move through the doc:

[image]

If you have more than 100 headers, it is hard to find a header with a word like "MySQL" if that word pops up every now and then elsewhere as well.

How to find only headers during keyword search? Is there a way to only search through the outline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this workaround: If you add a table of contents (Insert > Table of contents) at the begining of the page, you can use the normal search bar of the document and look at the first matches to see the corresponding headers, then you only need to navigate using the link.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Update: use Search & Navigate Add-on

[image]

In the example screenshot, you can search for "History" and it will highlight the header only, it will not search for "History" in the normal text.

> This simple add-on helps you quickly find and navigate to the necessary part of your document.
>
> Once you open the sidebar, you can switch between the list of headings, bookmarks, images, tables, and search results. Enter a keyword in the search field at the top to see all its entries in your document. A click on any entry in the list will take you to the paragraph you need to see.

#### Workaround: tag the headers

Tag your headers. Start any header with an often used word with #, or at least add the hashtag as soon as you once had the problem to find the header. In the example, this would make "MySQL" "#MySQL". Then you can quickly find just the header by searching for "#MySQL"